# Unsure about reason behind NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, command, classpath, noclassdeffounderror, runtimeexception

I have built a DLL which I am attempting to wrap Java code with, however I am having some troubles with running my Java program. I wrote a simple test DLL and Java program and am producing the same error, and although there are plenty of resources regarding NoClassDefFoundError online I can't seem to solve mine with any troubleshooting methods.

Here is my `D:\Test1.Java` file

```
public class Test1 { 

    static {
        //System.loadLibrary("HeyLand");
        System.load("D://HeyLand.dll");
    }

    public native void displayHeyLand();

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Test1 t = new Test1();
        t.displayHeyLand();
    }
}
```

After compiling, attempting to run `D:\Test1.class`results in the following:

```
D:\>java Test1.class
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Test1.class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Test1.class
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:660)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:358)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:626)
Could not find the main class: Test1.class.  Program will exit.
```

**Why I am stumped :**

1. I have set my classpath to be `D:\`, so I believe my class definition would be in the classpath, and I do not see how my compile-time and run-time classpaths could be any different. 

2. I don't see how this could have anything to do with static initialization, and I believe the exception would look different.

Perhaps I'm just missing something incredibly simple, I am very newbie with Java.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classpath environmental variable is taking precedence over that in the `java` run command. You need to specify the class location (as well as removing the `.class` file extension)

```
java -cp . Test1
```

Comment: It raises the exact same exception, I don't know why specifying the extension would have any impact on the command?

Comment: Does the class have a package declaration?

Comment: No, there isn't a package declaration.

Comment: Have you actually compiled the class?

Comment: I have compiled Test1.java, I was under the impression that a .class file was already compiled and was meant to be run be java in the command line....?

Comment: My apologies. How would you compile a class file? I compiled the java source file, to create the class file.

Comment: Only `.java` files are compiled. Once the class file exists the above command should work

Comment: Well yes, but my question is a result of it not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
Java normal syntax for executing class file is 
Java [<options>....} <class-name> [<arguments>....]


For example 

java com.package.name.Test1

here how compiler works

1. Compiler search for complete class name
2. Load that class
3. check for main method - in the same class
4. Call main method with passed arguments in command line string.



Now following are the possibilities why your class may not found main method.
1 - forgot to include package name
    I am new developer in java but I found when I run application using eclips or intellJ editor it gives different path and package name and execute code as I noticed it on command line edior. So make sure you are including package name 

    For example:
    java com.package.name.Test1 instead of 
    java Test1 

2. File name or pathname rather then class name
   As I noticed output file is in different location. That why class file path was different.
   java Test1.class
   java com/package/name/Test1.class

3. Typo


also I noticed you are using 
  static {
        //System.loadLibrary("HeyLand");
        System.load("D://HeyLand.dll");
    }


 Is this function ? or constructor? If it is function then where is name of the function? You cant write code without any reference in classs
```